# How to read values with same name but different values

Tags: php, android, mysql-workbench

I am writing a code and where I need to read from a database the amount of quantities of each parts, the problem is that the column quantity is the same to all the parts and when I assign them to my Android Studio code it prints me the same Value for all the requested fields. I need help on how can I tell the app to get the other Quantity
Query:

```
<?php
include "connection.php";
$consulta = "SELECT * from parts ;  ";
$result = $con -> query($consulta);

while($fila = $result -> fetch_array()){
    $usuarios[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $fila);
}

echo json_encode($usuarios);
$result -> close();
```

Output:

```
 [
    {"0":"1","idparts":"1","1":"resistor","partsName":"resistor","2":"13","Quantity":"13"},
    {"0":"2","idparts":"2","1":"capacitor","partsName":"capacitor","2":"10","Quantity":"10"},
    {"0":"3","idparts":"3","1":"inductor","partsName":"inductor","2":"10","Quantity":"10"},
    {"0":"4","idparts":"4","1":"multimeter","partsName":"multimeter","2":"10","Quantity":"10"},
    {"0":"5","idparts":"5","1":"arduino","partsName":"arduino","2":"10","Quantity":"10"},
    {"0":"6","idparts":"6","1":"rasberry","partsName":"rasberry","2":"10","Quantity":"10"},
    {"0":"8","idparts":"8","1":"wires","partsName":"wires","2":"10","Quantity":"10"},
    {"0":"9","idparts":"9","1":"breadboard","partsName":"breadboard","2":"10","Quantity":"10"}
]
```

I want to display output of quantity on android studio

here is android studio code for reading from database:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_action);

    logOut =  findViewById(R.id.signOut);

    resistor = findViewById(R.id.resistorQtyField);
    capacitor = findViewById(R.id.capacitorField);
    breadboard = findViewById(R.id.breadBoardField);
    inductor = findViewById(R.id.inductorQtyField);
    arduino = findViewById(R.id.arduinoQtyField);
    rasberry = findViewById(R.id.rasberryField);
    multimeter= findViewById(R.id.multimetroField);
    wires = findViewById(R.id.wireField);

    readInfo("http://192.168.0.16/APPEX/readInfo.php");
    logOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent back = new Intent(ActionActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(back);
        }
    });
}

 private void readInfo(final String URL) {
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(URL, new 
    Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            JSONObject jsonObject;
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    resistor.setText(jsonObject.getString("Quantity"));
                    capacitor.setText(jsonObject.getString("Quantity"));
                    breadboard.setText(jsonObject.getString("Quantity"));
                    inductor.setText(jsonObject.getString("Quantity"));
                    arduino.setText((jsonObject.getString("Quantity")));

                    multimeter.setText((jsonObject.getString("Quantity")));
                    rasberry.setText(jsonObject.getString("Quantity"));
                    wires.setText((jsonObject.getString("Quantity")));

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
  e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score 0):

`fetch_array` will by default return both a numeric array and an assoc array togther, you are just getting confused.

Instead us `fetch_assoc` and you will only get the assoc array and it will all make more sense

```
while($fila = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $usuarios[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $fila);
}
```

> Also from the json output you show, all but the first row, which has a `Quantity` of 13 have a `Quantity` of 10.